# OpenGL ES on Iphone: simple 2D animation (interpolation/tween)

Tags: iphone, opengl, animation, interpolation, tween

I'm working on an app that basically revolves around 2D shapes (mostly simple polygons) being dynamically drawn and animated.

I'm looking for a way to easily time my animations. It's basically just moving a vertex to a specified point in a specified time, so just interpolating floats, with all the usual easing parameters. I come from a Flash/ActionScript 3 environment, so if you're familiar with that, think Tween Classes.

I probably could easily be doing this with Core Animation (BasicAnimation etc), but i will have up to a hundred gradient-filled shapes with varying opacity being animated dynamically,
and I need good performance (60fps would be great). So i went for OpenGL ES. Plus I'm totally for investing time into learning something that I'll be able to reuse cross-platform.

So I know OpenGL is only for graphic rendering, and I'm not going to find any 2D animation methods built in. And I heard using CA with OpenGL (if feasible) was not a good idea performance-wise.
But before I look deeper into interpolation algorithms to increment my vertex's coordinates every frame, I juste wanted to make sure I wasn't totally missing out on something much easier!?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would look into the popular  [cocos2d](http://code.google.com/p/cocos2d-iphone/)  library.  It looks really nice; supports animation and uses OpenGL ES behind the scenes.

Comment: I heard about it but initially thought it was more sprite animation oriented. But you might be right, it does have transformation/easing actions and I'll definitely look into it and see how it can help. Thanks!